# IDE C (параметр /ZW)

Tags: c, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2013

Используется IDE Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013

> Ошибка    1   error D8048: невозможна компиляция файла C "pesok.c" с параметром /ZW   \visual studio 2013\Projects\App1\App1\App1.Windows\cl  App1.Windows

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то? Что за ошибка компиляции или про IDE?
IMHO, для винды лучше Visual Studio или интеловской IDE ничего нет.

Comment: Лучшая IDE для C по Windows - любая, которая умеет работать с gcc. Ибо поддержка C в gcc на сегодняшний момент самая полная и лучше всех. Уж всяко намного лучше, чем у студии. Мой выбор - Eclipse + CDT (правда, под Windows бываю очень редко, но чтобы рабочую среду не ломать)

Comment: 1. Что за ошибка в компиляции в vs?
2. Лучшая IDE для Си под виндой

Comment: @ALPHA, параметр /ZW [используется](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh561383.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) в приложениях Windows Store. Для компиляции кода на С надо использовать /TC. Скорее всего вы изначально выбрали не тот тип проекта который требуется.